# Symfony2 dynamic route based on tracked IP location in same bundle

Tags: symfony

I need my website to be accessible with optional parameter like

```
xyz.com  - show location selection page.  
xyz.com/mumbai/
xyz.com/london/
xyz.com/dubai/
```

Locations i.e mumbai, london etc. we are tracking with IP address and based on IP we redirect to domain.

I have tried to manipulate route in on Kernal request and able to access website based on location but unable to access xyz.com when some one access outside of specified location.

Does any buddy know how to do manipulate route based on parameters ?

Comment: Please be more specific. Consider adding some code samples of what you tried and what output you received vs. what you expected.

Comment: This looks similar as to an example from docs: https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#advanced-routing-example Is this what you are looking for? If so look for the LocaleListener as to see how the value gets set in case it's not provided in the url: https://github.com/symfony/http-kernel/blob/master/EventListener/LocaleListener.php